# Why do you think the number of answers with a score of at least 1 is decreasing significantly compared to total answers?

Tags: discussion

Why do you think the number of answers with a score of at least 1 is decreasing significantly, relative to total number of answers being posted for the period of 2016 and potentially 2017 till now?

As you can see here, [Total answers with a score 1 or more](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/193759/how-many-unique-answerers-per-month#graph) vs [Total answers posted](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/648969/how-many-unique-answerers-and-answers-per-month#graph). Is this because the community is becoming less appreciative as a whole or the quality of answers is getting low? Having underappreciated answerers or having a large number of low-quality answers, both are an issue for a community I feel.

We can also notice that the total number of unique users posting answers with a score of at least 1 is dropping while the number of unique answerers is more or less constant.

I wonder if the community already noticed this and if so, what steps the community can take about this issue.

Comment: Proper conclusion to draw is that there is no real point in keeping an unvoted answer around for more than a year.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with that. But I just wanted to see if there was any other conclusion that can be had on this. Thank you

Comment: @Hans - Not even then. For example, what if that answer is marked as the accepted one? Some good answers just don't get many views, especially if they are posted several days, or in some cases even several hours, after the question is posted. There is even a badge for having 0 score accepted answers.

Answer (score 15):

Answers posted last year have had a whole year to get upvotes, answers posted this year have not. Answers posted even earlier will have had even more time to garner upvotes.

Therefore there will be far more answers posted last year with upvotes compared to this year. Your analysis of the problem is fatally flawed.

Comment: Perhaps you can normalize (divide through) by time, making the assumption that the function of upvotes over time is linear.

Comment: I completely agree about the fact that answers posted in earlier years have had more time to get upvotes, I wanted to know if there were any other reasons around this. Because the number of answers being posted has been fluctuating at same level more or less since mid-2014, rather the usual growth it saw till then. And perhaps, if that could have contributed to less upvoted answers.

Comment: Also posts that have had no attention are auto deleted after a year so last years non deleted data will also look better.

Comment: This was an interesting point I wasn't aware of. Thanks for pointing this out :)